# Surface of revolution from data

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to plot a surface of revolution obtained by rotating a given curve *from data*, i.e. I have data points for two functions `f(y)` and `g(y)` and I would like to do something as follows (to get a minimal working example, I put `f(y)=sin(y)` and `g(y)=cos(y)`, but my main issue is to get these functions from data):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    view={30}{30}
    ]
\addplot3[surf,
    domain=0:360,
    samples=51,
    y domain=0:180, %% the domain should be as given in data
    z buffer=sort
]
({sin(y)*cos(x)}, %% want to replace sin(y) by f(y) from data
{sin(y)*sin(x)},
{cos(y)}); %%% want to replace cos(y) by g(y) from data
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that I have sufficiently many datapoints for the functions f and g, so no additional extrapolation should be necessary for a smooth looking plot.

What is the best way to do this? In particular I do not know how to import my data as functions that tikz/pgfplots can understand in this context.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: I suggest using asymptote (https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/index.html) instead of pgfplots, since it has better 3d rendering.